# How to use a test class from a jar in TestNG

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, testng

I have a JAR(xyz.jar) with test class `test.sample.ClassX`. I am trying to use this class in `testng.xml` shown below,

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="SuiteX" verbose="1" >
  <test name="TestX"   >
     <classes>
        <class name="test.sample.ClassX" />
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

My `pom.xml` has dependency(xyz.jar) added. I can execute this suite from eclipse but fails when i try to execute from command-line(mac) with below error,

```
error: package test.sample does not exist
```

Any idea what the issue might be ?

Comment: how are you triggerring from command line?

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml as well, showing the inclusion of the jar containing the tests and the surefire configuration.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you might not have a class defined like:

```
package test.sample;

public class TestX
{
...
```